# How to use ant JUnit task with

Tags: java, hibernate, ant, spring-test

I'm trying to add JUnit test automation to my CI server.  I have developed all the tests that need to run, and can run them locally from within eclipse.  I'm using Spring's testing library and JUnit4.  I run into the problem trying to get these tests run by my CI server.  It seems ant won't allow non-jar files on the classpath.  My test class relies on an applicationContext that it finds via the classpath:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations="test-config.xml")
@TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback=true,transactionManager="transactionManager")
public class DAOTest {
```

That context configuration file then references some sql files to load from the classpath:

```
<jdbc:embedded-database id="myDataSource" type="HSQL">
  <jdbc:script location="tables.sql"/>
  <jdbc:script location="testData.sql"/>
</jdbc:embedded-database>
```

And finally a Hibernate session factory points to hbm.xml files, of course from the classpath:

```
<bean id="mySessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
  <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource"/>
  <property name="hibernateProperties">
    <props>
      <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</prop>
      <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
      <prop key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory</prop>
      <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</prop>
      <prop key="hibernate.cache.user_query_cache">false</prop>
      <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">false</prop>
      <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">20</prop>
    </props>
  </property>
  <property name="mappingResources">
    <list>
      <value>resources/com/company/project/data/Session.hbm.xml</value>
      <value>resources/com/company/project/data/HistoricalSession.hbm.xml</value>
      <value>resources/com/company/project/data/RememberedData.hbm.xml</value>
    </list>
  </property>
</bean>
```

Since I am not able to provide any of these things on a classpath per ant's restrictions, anyone have an idea of how you're supposed to wire these things up?

EDIT: Updating with snippets from build.xml.  I have added the pathelement for the resources directory where everything I'm trying to reference lives, but haven't gotten it working yet.

My paths:

```
  <path id="master-classpath">
    <pathelement path="${project.classes.dir}" />
    <fileset dir="${project.lib.dir}">
      <include name="*.jar" />
    </fileset>
  </path>

  <path id="classpath.test">
    <path refid="master-classpath"/>
    <pathelement path="${project.test.dir}"/>
    <fileset dir="${project.testLibs.dir}">
      <include name="*.jar"/>
    </fileset>
    <pathelement path="resources"/>
  </path>
```

The test target:

```
  <target name="do-test" if="execute.tests">
    <pathconvert property="classpathProperty" refid="classpath.test"/>
    <echo>Classpath is ${classpathProperty}</echo>
    <delete dir="results"/>
    <mkdir dir="results"/>
    <mkdir dir="results/report"/>
    <junit printsummary="yes" showoutput="yes" fork="true" failureproperty="test.failed">
      <classpath refid="classpath.test"/>
      <formatter type="xml"/>
      <batchtest todir="results">
        <fileset dir="${project.test.dir}">
          <include name="**/*.java"/>
        </fileset>
      </batchtest>
      <test name="com.company.project.test.DAOTest" todir="results"/>
    </junit>
    <junitreport todir="results/report">
      <fileset dir="results" includes="*.xml"/>
      <report todir="results/report"/>
    </junitreport>
    <fail message="test failed" if="test.failed"/>
  </target>
```

The failure that I see each time is always "classpath resource [file] cannot be opened because it does not exist"

Comment: I think you need to find out what is wrong in your ant config. That has to work if you do it right. Add your and task definition to the question

Comment: I've added details from my build.xml.  To run the application in production, each hbm.xml file and applicationContext.xml are listed in the classpath.  I was expecting to do the same for this, but ant prohibits it.  Figuring out how to get around that has been leaving me stumped.

Comment: [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17248991/java-uti-zip-zipexception-error-while-calling-a-ant-target) shows what I mean by not being able to list the xml files themselves directly in the classpath